# Is there a way to modify context menu in iOS webView using Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: ios, cordova, titanium, appcelerator, contextmenu

I am using Appcelerator Titanium to develop an iOS app.

I have searched the web for quite a long time but still can't figure out how to add an item to the webView's context menu shown when tap and hold on a word. I wanna find a way to either disable the default 'copy|define' menu and replaced with my own, or add my custom action to it as a third option.
Does anyone can help or give me a hints?

Does Titanium provide such extension, or I need to switch to other framework like PhoneGap and write plugin instead? Appreciate if anyone can share their experience on developing similar feature.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Titanium. The webView acts like a browser so you can try doing this with "browser" javascript.

You can start from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)